# Copy image to Clipboard not working in Firefox & Chrome

Tags: javascript, asp.net, firefox, google-chrome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

I need one help regards JavaScript. I used this script in asp.net website.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function CopyToClip() {
            var imgControl = document.getElementById('imageControlWithImageToCopy');
            imgControl.contentEditable = 'true';
            var controlRange;

            if (document.body.createControlRange) {
                controlRange = document.body.createControlRange();
                controlRange.addElement(imgControl);
                controlRange.execCommand('Copy');
            }
            imgControl.contentEditable = 'false';
            return true;
        }
    </script>
```

This code for copying image (which is in an image control) to clipboard and it works fine in IE.

But this script is not working in Firefox & Chrome.

Please suggest any good solution to work in Firefox & Chrome

Comment: Seems like an exact dup.  Voting to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but you can't copy  stuff into the clipboard in Chrome or Firefox. Internet Explorer has a small hole that lets you do this, but it's the pretty much the only browser that supports that type of functionality any more.

There's a [Flash hack](http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/) to make this possible, but that's only for text, sorry.

Comment: Yes, most of the scripts supports text only.

Comment: Hi Friend,Any predefined jquery/ java script is there to support copying image to clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [here](http://www.shirmanov.com/2010/09/copy-to-clipboard-in-htmljavascript-and.html). Google chrome doesn't support copy to clipboard any more.
You might wanna look into flash possible options. Found [this one](http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/) one too, but no more development.

Comment: It won't help. These supports text only. We need solution for copying image to clipboard.

Comment: Yes, most of the scripts supports text only.

http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=1195035&start=0

The above site also discussing the same issue.

The following site said related to security issues,

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Granting_JavaScript_access_to_the_clipboard

but this won't work in latest version of Mozilla.